# How to write register from linux kernel module (cpu: ARM)

Tags: linux, memory, arm

I trying to write into system control register from linux kernel. But result is segmentation fault:

> Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 20050004

Code from kernel module:

```
#define REGBASE 0x20050000

void writeRegister(void){
    __raw_writel( 0x00000002, REGBASE + 0x0004 );
}
```

How to access on-chip memory where system control registers located?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What does `request_mem_region()` do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682422/what-does-request-mem-region-actually-do-and-when-it-is-needed)

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing that REGBASE is a physical address and not a virtual one. You need to ask the kernel to map it into the address space before you can use it. Most of the time you'd use `ioremap` to map it in.

For example:

```
void __iomem *io = ioremap(REGBASE, SZ_4K);
writel(0x00000002, io + 0x0004);
```

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

I know that is not exactly the answer you are looking for, but there is a way to do it in user space, if you want to avoid to program a kernel module for your application.

This is an example for GPIO access in Raspberry Pi3:

```
#define RASPBERRY_PI_PERI_BASE  0x3F000000
#define GPIO_BASE               (RASPBERRY_PI_PERI_BASE + 0x200000) // GPIO controller

#define BLOCK_SIZE              (4*1024)

static volatile uint32_t *gpio = NULL;

int GPIO_init(void) {
    int   fd;

    if ((fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_CLOEXEC) ) < 0) return -1; // printf("Failed to open /dev/mem, try checking permissions.\n");
    gpio = (uint32_t *)mmap(0, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, GPIO_BASE);
    if ((int32_t)gpio == -1) return -1; // printf("Failed mmap (GPIO): %s\n", strerror (errno)); 

    return 0;
}
```

Now you have a simply pointer variable *gpio that links to the hardware's memory address. You do it  mapping "mem" device on memory, that exists for you "for free" :-)

Regards.