# I/O memory region remap

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-device-driver, uart

The main reason for I/O memory region is to read/write anything to that memory.
If the register address is given, we can use readx/writex (x stands for b/l/w).

Then why do we have to use the address returned by io_remap which is nothing but the same as the address of the particular register given in the data sheet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does request\_mem\_region() actually do and when it is needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682422/what-does-request-mem-region-actually-do-and-when-it-is-needed)

Comment: You mean `ioremap`, not `io_remap`, right?

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski:yeah right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ioremap` is architecture specific function/macro. On some architectures it won't do anything and just basically return the address specified as an argument. It may do much more than that on other architectures, though. Take arm or x86 as an example - the `ioremap` will do a lot of checks before letting you using the memory region, for example.

What's more important than those checks, however, is that `ioremap` can setup a mapping of virtual addresses (from `vmalloc` area) to the requested physical ones and ensure that caching is disabled for addresses you are going to use. So in most cases pointer returned by `ioremap` will not be the same as just numeric address from the datasheet.

You want caching to be disabled because I/O registers are controlled by some external (from CPU point of view) devices. This means that processor can't know when its content changed, making cache content invalid.

Comment: :" mapping of virtual addressess "? why does virtual address comes into picture as there is direct accessing of the physical address? Does'nt it create an overhead? Why is caching disabled?

Comment: @Dino: I've edited my answer to describe why caching should be disabled. Linux requires virtual memory system in order to work normally so usually you don't have direct access to physical memory addresses without mapping.

Comment: @krzysztfof Adamski : Can you please answer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078968/call-to-request-mem-region-fails)

Answer (score 0):

The thing returned by `request_mem_region` is a `struct resource *`, you don't use it to access the I/O memory, and you don't have to do much of anything with it except check it for `NULL`. `request_mem_region` isn't part of the mapping you need to do to access the I/O, and your driver would actually (probably) work without it, but by calling it you make some information available in kernel data structures, and make sure that two drivers aren't trying to use overlapping memory ranges.

Comment: I have edited the question.instead of request_mem_region it is io_remap